Compute the value of a double sum
I need some help computing a(n apparently nasty) double sum:
$$f(l):=\sum_{j = \frac{l}{2}+1}^{l+1}\sum_{i = \frac{l}{2}+1}^{l+1} \binom{l+1}{j}\binom{l+1}{i} (j-i)^2$$
where $l$ is even. I'm not confident that there is a nice closed-form representation, but I do know (through some numeric simulations) that we have
$$\lim_{l \to \infty} \frac{f(l)}{l\cdot 2^{2l-1}} = 1-\frac{2}{\pi}$$
I'm not sure if this information is helpful, but it may prove useful. Regardless, while formally showing this limit holds should be sufficient for my purposes (so any help there would also be appreciated!), I am hopeful that computing the sum is possible.

With $\verb*\ell*$, write $\ell$ insted of $l$.


We put $l=2m$ and show the following is valid for $m\geq 0$:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{f(2m)}&=\sum_{j=m+1}^{2m+1}\sum_{i=m+1}^{2m+1}\binom{2m+1}{j}\binom{2m+1}{j}(j-i)^2\\
&\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{2}(2m+1)\left(2^{4m}-(2m+1)\binom{2m}{m}^2\right)}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

Since the double sum in (1) is symmetrical in $i$ and $j$ we can write $f(2m)$ as
\begin{align*}
f(2m)&=2\sum_{j=m+1}^{2m+1}\sum_{i=m+1}^{2m+1}\binom{2m+1}{j}\binom{2m+1}{i}\left(i^2-ij\right)\\
&=2\sum_{j=m+1}^{2m+1}\binom{2m+1}{j}\sum_{i=m+1}^{2m+1}\binom{2m+1}{i}\left(i(i-1)-(j-1)i\right)\tag{2}\\
\end{align*}
In order to calculate the inner sum we need the following building blocks:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{i=m+1}^{2m+1}\binom{2m+1}{i}}&=\frac{1}{2}\cdot2^{2m+1}\color{blue}{=2^{2m}}\\
\color{blue}{\sum_{i=m+1}^{2m+1}\binom{2m+1}{i}i}&=(2m+1)\sum_{i=m+1}^{2m+1}\binom{2m}{i-1}\\
&=(2m+1)\sum_{i=m}^{2m}\binom{2m}{i}\\
&\color{blue}{\,\,=\frac{1}{2}(2m+1)\left(2^{2m}+\binom{2m}{m}\right)}\\
\color{blue}{\sum_{i=m+1}^{2m+1}\binom{2m+1}{i}i(i-1)}&=(2m+1)(2m)\sum_{i=m+1}^{2m+1}\binom{2m-1}{i-2}\\
&=(2m+1)(2m)\sum_{i=m-1}^{2m-1}\binom{2m-1}{i}\\
&=(2m+1)(2m)\left(\frac{1}{2}2^{2m-1}+\binom{2m-1}{m}\right)\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=(2m+1)m\left(2^{2m-1}+\binom{2m}{m}\right)}
\end{align*}
We use the building blocks to simplify the inner sum in (2) and obtain after some rearrangements
\begin{align*}
f(2m)&=2\sum_{j=m+1}^{2m+1}\binom{2m+1}{j}\left((2m+1)m\left(2^{2m-1}+\binom{2m}{m}\right)\right.\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\left.-(j-1)\frac{1}{2}(2m+1)\left(2^{2m}+\binom{2m}{m}\right)\right)\\
&=(2m+1)\sum_{j=m+1}^{2m+1}\binom{2m+1}{j}\left((m+1-j)2^{2m}+(2m+1-j)\binom{2m}{m}\right)\\
&=(2m+1)\left((m+1)2^{2m}+(2m+1)\binom{2m}{m}\right)\sum_{j=m+1}^{2m+1}\binom{2m+1}{j}\\
&\qquad-(2m+1)\left(2^{2m}+\binom{2m}{m}\right)\sum_{j=m+1}^{2m+1}\binom{2m+1}{j}j\tag{3}
\end{align*}
Now we use the building blocks again to simplify the remaining sums in (3) and get after some simplifications
\begin{align*}
f(2m)&=2^{4m}(m+1)(2m+1)+2^{2m}(2m+1)^2\binom{2m}{m}\\
&\qquad-(2m+1)\left(2^{2m}+\binom{2m}{m}\right)\frac{1}{2}(2m+1)\left(2^{2m}+\binom{2m}{m}\right)\\
&=2^{4m}(m+1)(2m+1)+2^{2m}(2m+1)^2\binom{2m}{m}\\
&\qquad-\frac{1}{2}(2m+1)^2\left(2^{2m}+\binom{2m}{m}\right)^2\\
&=2^{4m}(m+1)(2m+1)+2^{2m}(2m+1)^2\binom{2m}{m}\\
&\qquad-\frac{1}{2}(2m+1)^22^{4m}-2^{2m}(2m+1)^2\binom{2m}{m}-\frac{1}{2}(2m+1)^2\binom{2m}{m}^2\\
&=(2m+1)\left(2^{4m}(m+1)-2^{4m-1}(2m+1)-\frac{1}{2}(2m+1)\binom{2m}{m}^2\right)\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{2}(2m+1)\left(2^{4m}-(2m+1)\binom{2m}{m}^2\right)}
\end{align*}
and the claim (1) follows.
Note: The limit value can be calculated by recalling the asymptotic behaviour of the central binomial coefficient
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\binom{2m}{m}\sim\frac{4^m}{\sqrt{\pi m}}}
\end{align*}

Writing $l=2k$, the sum in question is
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=k+1}^{2k+1} \sum_{j=k+1}^{2k+1} & \binom{2k+1}i \binom{2k+1}j (i^2-2ij+j^2) = \sum_{i=k+1}^{2k+1} \binom{2k+1}i i^2 \sum_{j=k+1}^{2k+1} \binom{2k+1}j \\
&\quad{}- 2 \sum_{i=k+1}^{2k+1} \binom{2k+1}i i \sum_{j=k+1}^{2k+1} \binom{2k+1}j j + \sum_{i=k+1}^{2k+1} \binom{2k+1}i \sum_{j=k+1}^{2k+1} \binom{2k+1}j j^2 \\
&= 2S_2S_0 - 2S_1^2,
\end{align*}
where
$\displaystyle
S_p = \sum_{j=k+1}^{2k+1} \binom{2k+1}j j^p
$. Certainly $S_0 = 4^k$, while (for what it's worth) Mathematica says
\begin{align*}
S_1 &= \binom{2 k+1}{k+2} \ {}_2F_1(2,1-k;k+3;-1)+\frac{\sqrt{\pi } (k+1) \binom{2
   k+1}{k+1} \Gamma (k+2)}{2 \Gamma (k+\frac{3}{2})} \\
S_2 &= \binom{2 k+1}{k+2} 
   \ {}_3F_2(2,2,1-k;1,k+3;-1) \\
&\qquad{}+\frac{(k+1) \left(4 \binom{2 k+1}{k+2} \ {}_2F_1(2,1-k;k+3;-1)
   \Gamma (k+\frac{3}{2})+\sqrt{\pi } (k+1) \binom{2 k+1}{k+1} \Gamma
   (k+2)\right)}{2 \Gamma (k+\frac{3}{2})}.
\end{align*}
